# Temperature conversion user input error

Tags: java

I need this program to be able to take a single character rather than taking the specified `double` to account for user error, then re-prompt the user for appropriate double, and I have also been forbidden from using hasNextDouble(), is this possible?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Temp
{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String prompt = "yes";

    do{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF");
        double degN = input.nextDouble();
        char degU = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        while(!(degU == 'C' || degU == 'F')){
            System.out.println("You must enter  F to convert from degF to degC"+
            " and C to convert to degC to degF");
            degU = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        }
        if(degU == 'F'){
            double fahrenheit = degN * 9/5 + 32;
            System.out.printf("%.2fF converted to Celsius is %.2fC.", degN, fahrenheit);
        }else{
            double celsius = (degN - 32) * 5/9.0;
            System.out.printf("%.2fF converted to Fahrenheit is %.2fC.", degN, celsius);
        }
        System.out.println("\n"+"Compute another temp - Enter yes or no");
        prompt = input.next().toLowerCase();
    }while(prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's just me but it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @peter.petrov it's not just you.

Comment: So if I put and 'N' rather than '100 F' I want it to reprompt the user. @peter.petrov

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `nextDouble()` call `next()`. It will resolve the string. The scanner class is well documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)